# Organizing bookmarks between Desktop and Android

Tags: bookmarks

I am  trying to manage my bookmarks both on my desktop and on my Android smartphone. My needs are as follows:

- I should be able to retrieve my bookmarks wherever I am, for instance on a PC I do not own
- there should be an Android client (obviously)
- there should be an easy way to add a bookmark from Firefox, for instance a bookmarklet

Do you have any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Andrea, please note that questions like *Can you suggest an app that does X?* are off topic on our site (see our [FAQ] for details).

Comment: Sorry, I did not know. Feel free to close the question, if that does not match your policies - I assumed it would be a rather standard question and did not check the policy beforehand

Comment: I would have recommended Xmarks, but it's not yet available for Firefox mobile. Wait for it. :)

Comment: @Andrea the name of our site may invite such questions (same for development issues which are also off topic) -- but "Android Enthusiasts but not developers and is-there-an-app and marketing and..." would be too long a name :) So we give friendly hints if one happens to place an OT question the first time. For ignorants who continue posting OT, we have other words reserved ;) In your case, it was just a friendly hint. Trick is to phrase it in a way we cannot complain: "How can I manage bookmars in a way compatible with Firefox..." would do it in your case (<- hint! ;)

Comment: @Izzy Thank you, I have edited the question. I hope it is more suitable now :-)

Comment: Fine with me now (maybe rephrase the title as well?). I meanwhile compiled an answer for you. Though it's not a bookmark manager in the classical way, this way you could manage bookmarks and notes, and even more. Hope you like it.

Answer (score 2):

Though it's in no way a classical bookmark manager, you could combine a few things:

[WikiMind note](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sweetrain.wikimind) is an editor with Wiki-Syntax support. So you can embed links and even structures easily (pictures as well)<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdaQG.jpg)</sup>. It stores all the data files on your SDCard, so they are easily accessible with other tools.

[image: WikiMind note] [image: FolderSync]

This fact (files on SDCard) you can put to use with [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite). As the screenshot<sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfJUv.jpg)</sup> shows, *FolderSync* supports a lot of cloud services: Box, Dropbox, Google Drive, Ubuntu One... It can also sync with local resources at home (e.g. Samba/Windows shares), or any FTP server, just to name a few examples. This way you can easily use your notes on multiple devices.

For usage on your desktop computer, there would be [WikiMind desktop](http://code.google.com/p/wiki-mind-desktop/issues/searchtips) and (even better) [ZimWiki](http://zim-wiki.org/).

**Further readings:** [S. W. Black: Writing tools for phone (Android) and desktop (Windows)](http://swblack.blogspot.de/2012/02/writing-tools-for-phone-android-and.html)

Comment: It is a little convoluted, but it may be a nice way to do this!

Comment: Admitted, not the "clean and easy" way. But as a side-effect you can do many other things with it: edit your documents (not just bookmarks), sync your other files (not just the wiki ones, but also e.g. photos, music files)... you get the idea. And I personally like things flexible. Already installed this combination to my tablet -- just did not yet find the time to play with it...

Answer (score 1):

Firefox can do this without any add-ons. It's called *Firefox Sync* and all you need is [Firefox on your PC](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) and [Firefox on your smartphone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox), then follow these steps to set it up:

- [Introduction](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-sync-take-your-bookmarks-and-tabs-with-you)
- [How do I set up Firefox Sync?](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-set-up-firefox-sync)
- [How do I add a device to Firefox Sync?](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-a-device-to-firefox-sync)

You can put your bookmarks in the `Unsorted Bookmarks` folder if you don't want to see them in your bookmarks toolbar. You can use tags there, too.

Comment: The problem is that I do not want to use the browser bookmarks. I put a lot of sutff in the browser bookmarks that I do not want to manage, and a lot of stuff in the managed bookmarks that I do not want to clutter my bookmarks menu. Moreover, I would not be able to use this feature when working on someone else's computer. I am looking for something like a cloud service. It should not be anything fancy, all I need is a simpel crud application with tagging, and an Android client.

Comment: Also, this would need me to use Firefox on Android, which is not the case (I mainly use Boat Browser)

Comment: @Andrea The clutter problem sounds like it could be easily solved with folders. And I use [Firefox Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable) to use my browser, settings and bookmarks on other computers, which works well.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but using portable apps is out of the way. I may as well have a text file with the urls and put that one on a pendrive, if I happen to have one with me, which most of the time is not the case. Also, using portable apps becomes complicated when you have to switch operating systems (I use Linux, but many of my friends run Windows or Mac)